# react: React-router Link not loading a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `login page` which has a `forgot password` link and it takes the user to forgot password page.

When I click on the `forgot password` link, it changes the URL but does not load the component.

**Code for login page**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// assets
import Logo from "../../../assets/images/kvh-logo.svg";
import bgImgArray from "../../../assets/images/bg";

import { Button, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon } from "reactstrap";

import "./Login.css";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const userid = useFormInput("");
  const password = useFormInput("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // for changing backgrounds
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid backgroundContainer">
      <div className="Login">
        <div className="login-form-container">
          <div className="logo">
            <img src={Logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <Form className="login-form">
              <InputGroup>
                <InputGroupAddon
                  className="input-group-addon"
                  addonType="prepend"
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                </InputGroupAddon>
                <Input
                  autoFocus
                  type="email"
                  aria-label="Username"
                  aria-describedby="username"
                  aria-invalid="false"
                  placeholder="Username or Email"
                  {...userid}
                />
              </InputGroup>
              <InputGroup>
                <InputGroupAddon
                  className="input-group-addon"
                  addonType="prepend"
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </InputGroupAddon>
                <Input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  aria-label="password"
                  aria-describedby="password"
                  {...password}
                />
              </InputGroup>
              <div className="form-actions">
                {error && (
                  <>
                    <small style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</small>
                    <br />
                  </>
                )}
                <br />
                <Button
                  className="pull-right"
                  block="true"
                  type="submit"
                  bssize="small"
                  value={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
                  onClick={handleLogin}
                  disabled={loading}
                >
                  Login
                </Button>
                <br />
              </div>
              <div className="forgotPassword">
                <Link to="/forgotPassword">Forgot password?</Link>
              </div>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const useFormInput = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  };
};

export default Login;
```

In routing code, I have Admin Layout which looks after the dashboard and AuthLayout which looks after the Login page.

I tried searching for the solution but unfortunately couldn't find any solutions. Hence, posting it here.

**Router Code**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth/Auth.js";
import ResetPassword from "../components/pages/reset-password/ResetPassword";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/" render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/auth" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

**Adding Auth Layout Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "../../components/pages/login/Login";
import ResetPassword from "../../components/pages/reset-password/ResetPassword";


import routes from "routes/routes.js";

class Pages extends React.Component {
  getRoutes = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.collapse) {
        return this.getRoutes(prop.views);
      }
      if (prop.layout === "/auth") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
  getActiveRoute = (routes) => {
    let activeRoute = "WATCH";
    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      if (routes[i].collapse) {
        let collapseActiveRoute = this.getActiveRoute(routes[i].views);
        if (collapseActiveRoute !== activeRoute) {
          return collapseActiveRoute;
        }
      } else {
        if (
          window.location.pathname.indexOf(
            routes[i].layout + routes[i].path
          ) !== -1
        ) {
          return routes[i].name;
        }
      }
    }
    return activeRoute;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("nav-open");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper wrapper-full-page" ref="fullPages">
        <div className="full-page">
          <Login {...this.props}></Login>
          <div className="forgotPassword">
            <Link to="/forgotPassword">Forgot password?</Link>
          </div>
          <Switch>
            {this.getRoutes(routes)}
            <Redirect from="*" to="/auth/login" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pages;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this code that you wrote:

```js
<Route path="/" render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
<Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
```

it's never going to `/forgotPassword` because path always match with first Route.
you should use `exact` props:

```js
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
<Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own `history` then you should use `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter`.

```
import {
  Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Because, `BrowserRouter` comes with its own `history` and you provide another one, this causes the problem.

Comment: How do you render your `Login` component?

Comment: From `AuthLayout`.

Comment: So, you can use `Link` there. Then, I put my 2 cents using the right `Router`. This is the very same problem using the wrong one.

Comment: I tried it out. same problem. I've also added my code for `AuthLayout`, for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap  inside Router as given below.

```
import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router><Link to="/forgotPassword">Forgot password?</Link> <Router/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced this issue with React 18.
Version of react was 18.0.1 and react-router-dom was 5.1.0 so StrictMode is causing the issue
Just remove or comment the Tag <React.StrictMode> and it should work fine.

Comment: Terrible suggestion. Please don't recommend removing the `React.StrictMode` component.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you've specified the order of the routes. The [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component "Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. The path `"/"` rendering the `AuthLayout` component will be matched by any URL path, the `"/forgotPassword"` route is unreachable.

Within the `Switch` component you should order the routes in ***inverse order of path specificity***. In other words, the ***more*** specific paths should be rendered prior to ***less*** specific paths. The idea is that if any given path doesn't match the URL path it "falls-through" to the less and less specific route paths until eventually it hits either a `"/"` or generic "catch-all" route.

There's an additional issue you'll hit after reordering the routes with the `"/"` route which will block the "catch-all" `Redirect`. For this one route you'll need to use the `exact` prop so only exactly `"/"` will match, and then any other path that wasn't already matched above will be safely handled by the redirect. Of course, for this redirect to work you actually need to render a route for `path="/auth"` somewhere. Below I've simply mapped it also to the `AuthLayout` route component.

Example suggestion:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
  <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
  <Route path={["/auth", "/"]} component={AuthLayout} />
  <Redirect to="/auth" />
</Switch>
```